# What free or paid text to speech framework/tool allows customizing the voice?

Tags: audio, speech-synthesis

What is a free text to speech tool that you can plugin your own voice to? Ideally one that works in the browser, but if it generates .wav or .mp3 files instead, that works too!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts:

- Apache-2.0 license
- Can customize the voice, see "Voice customization guide".
- State-of-the-art in 2022 for open-source AFAIK.